# Swift: How to "append" image to my text in uitextfield

Tags: swift

I would like to append an image to my text in uitextfield, and since the text in the textfield is never consistent I cannot use rightview. Any suggestions?

P/S: I used a textfield instead of label because tapping the textfield is supposed to trigger a picker view.

Comment: Why not use UIButton?

Comment: Can you add image to the back of the text?

Comment: You can use [autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) to align the image and button, while keeping the button as small as possible.

Comment: Then will the button's width be dynamically set based on the text length? also will auto layout auto position my image?
Also can button "summon" picker view as input view? Sorry I'm still considerably an amateur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, after scratching my head for the entire day, I ended up hide the text in my text field and add a uiLabel on top and an imageview beside it with autolayout and update the text.